# How to use Spring Batch to read CSV files which contains mutiple line in one cell?

Tags: spring, csv, spring-boot, file-io, spring-batch

Raw CSV is like this:

First line: Name, StudentID, comment

Data:

```
  Name, StudentId, Comment
  Jake, 12312, poor
  Emma, 12324, good
  Mary, 13214, need more work on programming
               and math.
```

The comment cell of the last entry of the csv data contains two lines. I want to treat it as one line data.

When I read the file using flatItemReader, it throws error about "expected token 3 but actual 1" I guess it treat the second line as a new line.
Is there a way to treat them as one line?

Answer (score 0):

Have your reader just return the raw string for each line without trying to split on the delimiter.  Make a processor (has to be stateful) to handle the parsing.  The only tricky part is you'll have to signal to the processor when you've reached the EOF somehow so it isn't waiting to see if it should aggregate the next line.  Something like this:

```
public class AggregatingItemProcessor<T> implements ItemProcessor<T, T>, InitializingBean {

    private BiPredicate<T, T> aggregatePredicate;
    private BiFunction<T, T, T> aggregator;

    public void setAggregatePredicate(BiPredicate<T, T> aggregatePredicate) {
        this.aggregatePredicate = aggregatePredicate;
    }

    public void setAggregator(BiFunction<T, T, T> aggregator) {
        this.aggregator = aggregator;
    }

    private T cur;

    @Override
    public T process(T item) throws Exception {
        if(cur == null) {
            cur = item;
            return null;
        }
        if(aggregatePredicate.test(cur, item)) {
            cur = aggregator.apply(cur, item);
            return null;
        } else {
            T toRet = cur;
            cur = item;
            return toRet;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(aggregatePredicate, "Predicate to determine if records should be aggregated must not be null.");
        Assert.notNull(aggregator, "Function for aggregating items must not be null.");
    }
}
```

Then the config...

```
static final String EOF_MARKER = "\0";

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader() {
    final FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<String>() {

        private boolean finished = false;

        @Override
        public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
            if(finished) return null;
            String next = super.read();
            if(next == null) {
                finished = true;
                return EOF_MARKER;
            }
            return next;
        }

    };
    reader.setLineMapper((s, i) -> s);
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public AggregatingItemProcessor<String> processor() {
    final AggregatingItemProcessor<String> processor = new AggregatingItemProcessor<>();
    processor.setAggregatePredicate((s1, s2) -> !EOF_MARKER.equals(s2) && StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(s2, ",") < 2);
    processor.setAggregator(String::concat);
    return processor;
}
```